# Как в JS изменить Html код который находится в переменной?

Tags: javascript, html

С помощью

```
async function getBlock(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const text = await res.text()
  return text
 }
```

загружается html код в переменную, но можно ли этот html загруженный в переменную изменить?

Как

> document.getElementById("id").innerHTML

для активной страницы, только в пемеренной.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример через DOMParser:

```js
let sourceString = "<span id='test'>test</span>";
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(sourceString, "text/html");
doc.querySelector('#test').textContent = 'qweqwe';

console.log(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: чет я не успел :D

Comment: `doc.body.innerHTML`  надо. поэтому не успел :D

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
Но есть одна проблема в том что я хочу разместить внутри `<table id='test'></table>`
строки и столбцы, а как я вижу в консоли символы переводятся в `&lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td class="td-con"&gt;TESTTESTTEST&lt;/td&gt;`
И на страницу выводится код "как для копирования"

Comment: Разобрался
`doc.querySelector('#test').textContent`
Заменил на
`doc.querySelector('#test').innerHTML`